# Redirect "https" to "http" for one domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

We have an issue where a Google search for our site leads to a HTTPS link to our domain.  But we have no cert on the domain so people get security warnings.

We need to introduce an Apache rewrite rule that directs people to http://, but also only does it for this one domain (let's say 2fyi.com), and doesn't touch our other rewrite rules.

I'm trying this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} 2fyi.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

But it's not working.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Redirect http to https without certificat, you may have browser certificate warning before the redirect. This loses the purpose.

Comment: @BrianMayer: What is not working?

Comment: Are you trying to add flags in your rewrite rule, as : `RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]` ?